# How to compare two columns in mySql one of them Json

Tags: mysql, json

I have Two tables in mysql database and I want to compare two columns each of them in a different table first table name "oc_product_option_value" has column:

```
product_option_value_id   

20
21
22
23
50
100
```

and second table "oc_cart" has cuolomn

```
option

{"20":"228","24":"229"}
```

I want compare two table and select data from first table where "product_option_value_id"  in second table.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value 
WHERE product_option_id IN
(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(OPTION,'{',''),'}',''),':',','),'"','')
as `option` FROM `oc_cart`)
```

and no result

```
* columns Structure 

"product_option_value_id" is int 
"option" is TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Heum.. Not sure that it will do what you expect but I think it's a first step:

1/ Returns only rows wich have a matching value in second table (`oc_cart`)

```
SELECT *
FROM oc_product_option_value acpoa
JOIN oc_cart acc ON acc.option REGEXP concat('"', acpoa.product_option_value_id, '"');
```

Be careful about naming a column with a reserved MySQL word (`option`)

**EDIT :**

2/ If you want to display a "result" *(`final_kept_column`)* after this comparison in order to display "`value_id`" or "`option`" even if there's no matching value in `oc_cart`, you can try someting like this :

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN acc.option IS NULL 
          THEN acpoa.product_option_value_id 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS final_kept_column
FROM oc_product_option_value acpoa
LEFT JOIN oc_cart acc ON acc.option REGEXP concat('"', acpoa.product_option_value_id, '"');
```

Hope this help